# Deploy image from Azure Container Registry to an Azure Linux Virtual Machine

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

I have created a build-pipeline which builds my docker based project. The image is being pushed to the Azure Container Registry.

What I want to achieve is to deploy the image to a virtual machine but I have no idea where to start. Do I for example need to create a release pipeline which executes a script on the virtual machine which results in the image being pulled and run?

Hope some can help me out with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automate the process to deploy the image to a virtual machine via azure pipeline. You need to create a pipeline, or add an additional agent job or step which executes the dock commands on the virtual machine to your existing pipeline. Check out below possible workarounds:

1, Create a self-hosted agent on the virtual machine. See tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) for detailed steps.

Then you can add an additional agent job or create a release pipeline to run the docker commands in a script task. And configure the agent pool to run the job on your self-hosted agent pool.

For below example. I add an additional job and execute the docker commands in a powershell task to run the image:

```
stages:
- stage: 
  jobs: 
  - job: Build
    steps:
    ...

  - job: Deploy
    dependsOn: Build
    pool: Default  #run this job on the self-hosted agent which is hosted on the VM.
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        docker login CONTAINERREGISTRYURL -u CONTAINERREGISTRYNAME -p CONTAINERREGISTRYPASSWORD
        docker run ....
```

2, If you donot want to create a self hosted agent. You can also try using one of below tasks in your pipeline, which allow you run the dock scripts on the target Virtual machine.

[PowerShell on Target Machines task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops)

[SSH Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

> Do I for example need to create a release pipeline which executes a
> script on the virtual machine which results in the image being pulled
> and run?

Actually, yes. As you said, you want to deploy the image in the virtual machine. It means you treat the VM as a docker server and run containers in it, then you need to execute the commands inside it. So the steps would like this:

1. Install and configure the Docker server;
2. Login the Azure Container Registry;
3. Pulled the image from Azure Container Registry;
4. Deploy the image in the VM.

In my side, execute a script with all the commands is better then execute the commands separately.