# Create an Azure VM copy locally and deploy it on a different instance

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, virtual-machine

I want to create a baseline copy of Azure VM, Install all SQL and some 3rd party software I needed to it and create a copy / backup of it locally.

This copy / backup can be re-deployed again to a new VM for a new client.

currently I'm spending 1 to 2 days setting up this VM, installing and configuring this server.

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use any configuration management tools Ansible, Puppet, Chef...

Docker is the simplest thing I can think of. Upload your own image to a registry and then spawn as many VMs using it as you want.

See this for some pointers: [Deploy image from Azure Container Registry to an Azure Linux Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060128/deploy-image-from-azure-container-registry-to-an-azure-linux-virtual-machine)

Ansible and other CM tools will give you more functionality for more effort.